# Rocket Exhaust Ground Impact: Exhaust Gas Velocity vs. Pressure

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, vacuum, estimation, rocket-science

Thanks for anyone that can help.

Say we have a rocket engine in the vacuum of space with exhaust velocity of 2,000m/s or more, but low pressure exiting nozzle, say 1-2psi. A wider nozzle engineered for space, with low exhaust pressure. The rocket is landing on an asteroid, a crater, a moon, whatever. Something with no atmosphere still in the hard vacuum of space.

The low pressure would seem to indicate that the exhaust gas does little damage because it is dispersed. The high velocity would seem to indicate that it would do damage because of its high kinetic energy. This contradiction is confusing me.

How much pressure, or velocity, is needed to do various kinds of damage to ground below?

Two other questions, if anyone feeling generous.

1. How rapidly would heat dissipate from exhaust after leaving nozzle?
2. Why would the exhaust leaving nozzle slow down as it approaches the ground?

I suspect the answer is very simple, to the main question.

Comment: Suppose you had a gun that shot little fast bullets. Suppose you had one that shot big slow bullets. How much damage would they do? It depends on how big, how fast, and what they hit. It is hard to answer. The answer is complex.

Comment: The bullets are the same size here. The exhaust gas particles. They have low exhaust pressure exiting the nozzle, but high velocity. Any more insights? And thank you.

Comment: Nothing really on what you are asking. Here is a video on how rockets are optimized for vacuum or air. [Are Aerospikes Better Than Bell Nozzles?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4SaofKCYwo).

Comment: There was a probe that sampled an asteroid and was a loose pile of rubble weakly held together by its gravity. The probe gently touched down and nearly sank out of site. It blasted away lots of matter with very weak engines.